# SQL query optimization practice

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I want to pratice my skills in SQL query optimization for small databases.
I have created a very simple database:
[image]

I populated it with hunderds of thousands of entries and need some complex, stupid and unoptimized queries to make some tests and practice my optimization skills. Right now I tried to write some queries but they don't make much impact on the database.

Which key words should I use? Could someone help?

Comment: It would be nice to have info about the dbms you are using, as different databases have different methods to tune performance, and to  analyze queries.

Comment: Some way to get really unoptimized queries is trying to join on unindexed columns,

Comment: That's a good point:
I'm using oracle database in version 18c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to come up with queries that are really bad :-) Here are some ideas. Hopefully, others will come up with more. I suggest you put your tables (empty or even with some sample rows) in https://dbfiddle.uk/, where we can try our queries. I don't know for instance, if I don't have any syntax errors in below queries.

### Find all videos that are either owned or commented by a user named xyz:

```
select distinct v.*
from videos v
left join user_have_videos uv on uv.video_id = v.video_id
left join users u1 on u1.user_id = uv.user_id
left join comments c on c.video_id = v.video_id
left join users u2 on u2.user_id = c.user_id
where u1.user_name = :user_name
   or u2.user_name = :user_name;
```

### Find all users that own at least three different videos:

```
select distinct u.*
from users u
left join user_have_videos uv1 on uv1.user_id = u.user_id
left join videos v1 on v1.video_id = uv1.video_id
left join user_have_videos uv2 on uv2.user_id = u.user_id
left join videos v2 on v2.video_id = uv2.video_id
left join user_have_videos uv3 on uv3.user_id = u.user_id
left join videos v3 on v3.video_id = uv3.video_id
where v1.video_id <> v2.video_id
  and v1.video_id <> v3.video_id
  and v2.video_id <> v1.video_id
  and v2.video_id <> v3.video_id
  and v3.video_id <> v1.video_id
  and v3.video_id <> v2.video_id;
```

### Find all users that commented on John Wayne:

```
select distinct u.*
from users u
join comments c on c.user_id = u.user_id
where lower(comments) like '%john wayne%';
```

### And here is one where you shall find out what this does and make it better:

```
with cte(user_id, video_id, num) as
(
  select u.user_id, v.video_id, 1
  from videos v
  join user_have_videos uv on uv.video_id = v.video_id
  join users u on u.user_id = uv.user_id
  union all
  select u.user_id, min(v.video_id), min(cte.num) + 1
  from videos v
  join user_have_videos uv on uv.video_id = v.video_id
  join users u on u.user_id = uv.user_id
  join cte on cte.user_id = u.user_id 
           and cte.video_id < v.video_id
  group by u.user_id
)
select distinct u.*
from users u
join cte on cte.user_id = u.user_id and cte.num >= 10;
```